# Magento Checkout Redirecting to Cart page

Tags: magento, paypal

When i try to do purchase by clicking place order button in magento,it redirects from checkout page to cart page.This happens only when I select paypal website payments pro as payment method.Paypal express checkout works fine.Magento does not show error in system.log or in exception.log

Magento version - 1.5.1.0.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure your "paypal website payments pro" is configured correctly?

Comment: @Dick Yes.This happened after migrating it to new server

Comment: In this case I have two guesses. Maybe your old server IP is somehow tied to your Paypal account (not sure, never worked with "paypal website payments pro") or there's some library like cUrl or openSSL required and missing (disabled) at your new server.

Comment: Some of the other magento websites in same server are running smoothly

Comment: "Maybe your old server IP is somehow tied to your Paypal account (not sure, never worked with "paypal website payments pro")", no, this is not possible with Website Payments Pro. @blakcaps what's in your error log and Magento notifications?